# filtering boolean value on aggregate method in pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm trying to use the aggregate method on `pymongo` like so:

```
fnObjs.aggregate([
    {'$match': {'sha1_duplicate': false}}
])
```

I'm getting :

```
NameError: global name 'false' is not defined
```

The query does works on the mongo cli.

Comment: why is there an extra quote after `sha1_duplicate`? typo?

Comment: It has been deleted during a previous edit, it was in the original post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error message says, `false` is not defined, because in Python, the boolean have a capital letter, so it's `False` and `True`.